# Shiny - Input Argument Not Accessible

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to take input from a slider in shiny and use it in the server section by calling a function on it to obtain information for graphing. However, the input from the slider is not recognized serverside, and throws an error.

> Evaluation error: argument "hour" is missing, with no default.

The `inputID` matches the argument so I don't understand why it wouldn't be able to access it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
get_data <- function(foo){return(foo)}

#build shiny app
header <- dashboardHeader(
            title="Data"
          )
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Charts and Analysis", tabName = "charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), 
             menuSubItem("Temperature by Time of Day", tabName = "temperatures", icon = NULL)        )        
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "temperatures",
      fluidRow(
        box(
            title = "Time of Day",
            sliderInput(inputId = "hour", label="Hour (military)", min=0, max=23, value=12, step=1)
        ),
        box(plotOutput("series"))
      )
    )


  )


)


ui <- dashboardPage(skin="green", header, sidebar, body)
server <- function(input, output) { 

  MR <- get_data(strtoi(input$hour))
  output$series <- renderPlot({
    plot(x=MR, y=MR) 
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a shiny application calls to input parameters must be in a reactive context.
Then we must move the functional assignment into the `renderPlot` function.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
get_data <- function(foo){return(foo)}

#build shiny app
header <- dashboardHeader(
            title="Data"
          )
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Charts and Analysis", tabName = "charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), 
             menuSubItem("Temperature by Time of Day", tabName = "temperatures", icon = NULL)        )        
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "temperatures",
      fluidRow(
        box(
            title = "Time of Day",
            sliderInput(inputId = "hour", label="Hour (military)", min=0, max=23, value=12, step=1)
        ),
        box(plotOutput("series"))
      )
    )


  )


)


ui <- dashboardPage(skin="green", header, sidebar, body)
server <- function(input, output) { 


  output$series <- renderPlot({
    MR <- get_data(strtoi(input$hour))
    plot(x=MR, y=MR) 
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```